# Opencv Different Color Detection

Tags: android, opencv, contour

I want  to detect  red and orange color objects detection. This code works for  just show red color of object or just show orange color of object.How can I show  red and orange color object detection?

```
    Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba , mHsv, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV);

    Scalar lowerThreshold = new Scalar (159, 135, 135); // Red color – lower hsv values
    Scalar upperThreshold = new Scalar (179, 255, 255); // Red color – higher hsv values

    Scalar lowerThreshold2 = new Scalar (5,50,50); // Orange color – lower hsv values
    Scalar upperThreshold2 = new Scalar (15, 255, 255); // Orange color – higher hsv values

    Core.inRange ( mHsv, lowerThreshold , upperThreshold, mMaskMat );
    Core.inRange ( mHsv, lowerThreshold2 , upperThreshold2, mMaskMat2 );
    Imgproc.dilate ( mMaskMat, mDilatedMat, new Mat() );
    Imgproc.dilate ( mMaskMat2, mDilatedMat, new Mat() );

    // contours
            List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
    Imgproc.findContours ( mDilatedMat, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );

     for ( int contourIdx=0; contourIdx < contours.size(); contourIdx++ )
      {
         if (Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(contourIdx)) > 1000) {

             Imgproc.drawContours ( mRgba, contours, contourIdx, new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 5);
         }
      }
```

Comment: Aren't you overwriting mMaskMat. Try, using Use 2 masks and obtain final mask using bitwise_and operation. Also, how did you get mDilatedMat? Next, even with overwrite of mask, you should obtain orange-colored objects, not red one.

Comment: you are overwriting the mMaskMat. use diff maskmat and till finding contours handle the case for orange and red separately, then draw contours on same image

Comment: @ saurabheights I editted my code.  mDilatedMat = new Mat(); is defined. But how can I defie two times using contour?I mean contour should be 2 times?

Comment: @ Garvita Tiwari  I editted my code.  mDilatedMat = new Mat(); is defined. But how can I defie two times using contour?I mean contour should be 2 times?

Comment: @diad: Apologies, I should have mentioned `bitwise_or` instead of `bitwise_and`. Please check your dilate statements, the output of first statement is overwritten by second dilate statement. Try this: 1. Merge both mMaskMat and mMaskMat2 together using bitwise_or(http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#bitwise-or). 2. Use a single dilate method.

Comment: @diad any updates on how did it go?